# Tensorflow 2.3 pipeline load all the data to the RAM

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tf.data.dataset

I created pipeline using **tf.data** API, for reading data set of images. I have a big dataset with high resolution. However, each time trying to reading all the dataset, the computer crash because the code using all the RAM. I tested the code with about 1280 images, it works without any error. But when I used all the datasets the model craches.
So, I am wondering if there is a way to make **tf.data** read a one or two batch in front not more than that.

This the code I am using to create the pipeline:

```
    def decode_img(self, img):
        img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32, saturate=False)
        img = tf.image.resize(img, size=self.input_dim, antialias=False, name=None)
        return img

    def get_label(self, label):
        y = np.zeros(self.n_class, dtype=np.float32)
        y[label] = 1
        return y

    def process_path(self, file_path, label):
        label = self.get_label(label)
        img = Image.open(file_path)

        width, height = img.size
        # Setting the points for cropped image
        new_hight = height // 2
        new_width = width // 2
        newsize = (new_width, new_hight)
        img = img.resize(newsize)

        if self.aug_img:
            img = self.policy(img)
        img = self.decode_img(np.array(img, dtype=np.float32))
        return img, label

    def create_pip_line(self):

        def _fixup_shape(images, labels):
            images.set_shape([None, None, 3])
            labels.set_shape([7])  # I have 19 classes
            return images, labels

        tf_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((self.df["file_path"].values, self.df["class_num"].values))
        tf_ds = tf_ds.map(lambda img, label: tf.numpy_function(self.process_path,
                                                               [img, label],
                                                               (tf.float32, tf.float32)),
                          num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
        tf_ds = tf_ds.map(_fixup_shape)

        if not self.is_val:
            tf_ds = tf_ds.shuffle(len(self.df), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
        tf_ds = tf_ds.batch(self.batch_size).repeat(self.epoch_num)
        self.tf_ds = tf_ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue in my code was the Shuffle function. This function takes two parameters, the first one number of data to shuffle, the second one the repeat for each epoch.
However, I found the number of data that will be loaded to the memory depends on this function. Therefore, I reduced the number from all data to 100 and this makes the pipeline load 100 images and shuffles them then load another 100, and so on.

```
if not self.is_val:
            tf_ds = tf_ds.shuffle(100, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
```